# Large query on a custom table - memory issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

I'm building a plugin that creates codes that can be redeemed by a user. I need to display all of the generated codes in a WP_LIST_TABLE. I have created a custom table called "bo_codes" and it looks like this.

Table: https://visual23.com/table.png

My query looks like this.

```
$query = "
SELECT $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.bo_code, $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.assigned_product_name, $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.status, $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.run_number, $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.author_name, $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.date_created
FROM $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes
ORDER BY $wpdb->bo_vaping_codes.date_created DESC;
";
$data = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
```

I did a test and generated 100,000 codes and I get this error.
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)"

Is there anything I can do with the database or my query to reduce the memory used? I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or am I just pushing its limits.

Comment: No user would ever want to review a list of 100k items. Use paging to display a subset of the records only.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're selecting the entire table because there's no 'where' clause.  It's hard to instruct you with what to do because I'm not sure how this is being used.

Comment: @Shadow This data goes into a WP_LIST_TABLE that shows 15 items at a time and paginates. It seems like the WP_LIST_TABLE still has to load all of the records and then does its own pagination.

Comment: @Gerik I didn't add a WHERE clause because I actually need to get every row. The data is being used to populate a WP_LIST_TABLE in a plugin Admin screen. Basically it shows all codes generated. thanks!

Comment: The piece of code you show do not have any paging. Either populate the table in question using insert ... select ... or page the data before inserting everything into the target table.

Comment: Hey @Robb, I agree with Shadow here: the best thing to do is to alter the query so the pagination is taken into account when obtaining the data from the db.  No user would need to see 100,000 records at once and even if the code is already doing some pagination this query and code structure just isn't very resource friendly.

Comment: @Shadow how would I go about adding paging to the query? Using LIMIT and OFFSET? I'm just confused because the query happens in the prepare_items() in the WP_List_Table class and it has pagination built in. All of that works great when I have less records to query. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's the problem when you use a built-in framework that was not designed in your use case in mind. You may have to re-think the process and not to use the list table at all. The piece of code in your question tries to retrieve all records from a table and transfer them to an array within php. That's the cause for the out of memory message. I do not think that your design is good enough.

Comment: @Shadow Yep, I think you're right. I was able to tweak it to only load 10 at a time and have the pagination working. I'm using "LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $per_page;" Although right now I have to bake in the total number of records. The records will never be removed so I could store and update the total items each time a batch of codes is created. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with wp, but honestly, I would simply use insert ... select ... to transfer larger amounts of data between two tables. This way the client side (the php code in this case) is completely left out from the transfer process, therefore there cannot really be any memory issues.

Comment: @Shadow I think there was some confusion. WP_List_Table is a WP Class that is for a visual data table that's used for a plugin Admin screen. Sorry about that!

Comment: https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/

Comment: Well, this shows how much I know about wordpress :)

Comment: Pagination is unreasonable -- back to the first Comment:  _No user would ever want to review a list of 100k items._  I'll add on:  "whether paginated or not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UI design issue, not a database issue.

Pagination is unreasonable -- back to the first Comment:  *No user would ever want to review a list of 100k items.*  I'll add on:  "whether paginated or not".  So,  Re-think the UI; decide on a way to show useful info without offering it all.

Maybe first ask which "product category" to list the items for.

Maybe first by the "author".

Maybe by which month it was "created" in.

Whatever makes sense to the app.  But make sure that the grouping does not lead to an unreasonably long list of things to then show all at once or paginate through.

For 100K items, it is probably reasonable to go through *two* levels of picking before getting to the actual list.  That will mostly keep things down to under 100 things to pick among at a time.

Comment: You're totally right and I'm going back to the agency to have them rethink this section.

Comment: @RobbBennett - Yes; push back!  All too many websites and devices anger me because of their designer's failure to think about the User Interface.